# How to find the Limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the following question first I thought I could use Caesaro's result somehow to solve this but it went nowhere.
[image]

Kindly help with this problem I am missing the correct approach.

Thanks and regards in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

By **[Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)** we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i}{s_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_ix_i-\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i}{s_{n+1}-s_n}$$

when the RHS exists.

Comment: I am not aware of this theorem@gimusi any links will be helpful.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana I've added a reference for that theorem.